# How to get the script to only return one letter of the first name they Input?

Tags: shell

I am trying to figure out how to get only the first letter of the first name they input but everything I tried or look at other similar problems doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
name = input("name:")
first_letter = name[0] 
print(first_letter)
```